# SQL JOIN - SELECT newest time interval based on ID and timestamp

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables (see below), `T1` with `ID` and `TIMESTAMP` columns and another `T2` with `ID` and two timestamps which act as an interval, `START_TIME` and `END_TIME`.  For `T1` there can be duplicate `ID`s, but never duplicate timestamp values per `ID`.  For `T2` there can be duplicate `ID`s but the intervals will never be duplicate.  The intervals can have the same `START_TIME` but never the same `END_TIME`.  Also, the `START_TIME` will typically increase (become more recent), but not always, but will never decrease.  The `END_TIME` can vary, will typically increase, but can decrease (but never less than the `START_TIME`).

Point of saying all that is for a given `TIMESTAMP` from `T1`, it could fall into many intervals from `T2` when joined based on the `ID` and `TIMESTAMP` between `START_TIME` and `END_TIME`.

I am trying to join `T1` and `T2` on the `ID` and where the `TIMESTAMP` falls between the newest (most recent) interval from `T2`.

`T1`

| ID | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 08:05:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 08:07:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 15:45:00 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 20:01:00 |

`T2`

| ID | START_TIME | END_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 00:05:00 | 2021-01-01 07:05:00 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 01:05:00 | 2021-01-01 09:30:00 |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 07:05:00 | 2021-01-01 13:30:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 07:35:00 | 2021-01-01 09:30:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 09:00:00 | 2021-01-01 10:05:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 12:00:00 | 2021-01-01 16:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 13:00:00 | 2021-01-01 17:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 15:00:00 | 2021-01-01 18:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 18:00:00 | 2021-01-01 23:59:00 |

The results of the `JOIN` should return
`RESULTS`

| [T1 or T2].ID | T1.TIMESTAMP | T2.START_TIME | T2.END_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 08:05:00 | 2021-01-01 07:05:00 | 2021-01-01 13:30:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 08:07:00 | 2021-01-01 07:35:00 | 2021-01-01 09:30:00 |
| 2 | 2021-01-01 15:45:00 | 2021-01-01 15:00:00 | 2021-01-01 18:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021-01-01 20:01:00 | 2021-01-01 18:00:00 | 2021-01-01 23:59:00 |

How do I find the newest interval to match the results above?

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.START_TIME, T2.END_TIME
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
AND (???)
-- I'm assuming there is a subquery buried in the INNER JOIN somewhere, but just can't piece it together
```

***I tried to abstract away as much as possible, but am using Snowflake SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a good place to use a `lateral join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 left join lateral
     (select t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.id = t1.id and
            t1.timestamp between t2.start_time and t2.end_time
      order by t2.start_time desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) t2
     on 1=1;
```

EDIT:

It is a shame that the above cannot be evaluated.  Here is another version:

```
select t12.*
from (select t1.*, t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t2.start_time desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1 left join lateral
           table2 t2
         on t2.id = t1.id and
            t1.timestamp between t2.start_time and t2.end_time

     ) t12
where seqnum = 1;
```

You will need to adjust the columns in the subquery to avoid duplicate column names.

Comment: I tried something similar before posting, but just used a Left Outer Join and TOP 1 * instead of the limit 1.  The system kept throwing back that `t1.id` in the line `where t2.id = t1.id and` is an invalid identifer.  Not sure if that's a system thing or not?!?

Comment: @user2715877 . . . Did you use a lateral join or not?  This is the syntax for a lateral join.

Comment: Yes, I did try exactly as you posted.  However, I had to remove the `limit 1` (would not run with that line) and the query is returning a subset (only the matches) of the overall rows in `T1`.  With the `left join` shouldn't it return all of `T1`?

Comment: Upon further inspection of the `lateral`, it will only return the matches.  If there were another row in `T1`, `ID`=4 and `TIMESTAMP`=2021-01-01 23:14:00.  How would the query change to ensure all the rows in `T1` were returned?  Should I update the original post?

Comment: @user2715877 . . . `left join lateral` returns *all* rows in `table1`, so I don't know what your comment is referring to.  As for the `limit` -- Snowflake uses `fetch first 1 row` or `select top`.

Comment: Yes, the statement you provide based on the original `T1` will return all the rows.  But, what if there is an `ID` in `T1` that is not in `T2`?

Comment: @user2715877 . . . I will repeat:  `left join lateral` should return all rows in `table1`, even if there are no matches.  I realize I left out the `on` clause; that is now fixed.

Comment: `on 1=1` helped in returning rows, but `fetch first 1 row only` or `select top 1` returning `SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated`.

Comment: Would the results be different from your edited answer if one used a "normal" (non-lateral) left outer join?

Comment: @user2715877 . . . The code wouldn't work with a "normal" join.